# Do two test statistics at the same $\alpha$ value give the same TYPE 1 error rate and same decision?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, frequentist

Do two test statistics at the same $\alpha$ value give the same TYPE 1 error rate and same decision? I think it is clear that they do give the same TYPE 1 error rate by definition, but do they always imply the same decision? In other words, is it possible for one test statistic to reject the null while the other fail to reject? If not, would any one please give me an elementary example?

Comment: Not necessarily, for instance you cannot interpret the same p value in the same fashion if coming from a t test or a Mann-Whitney U test when the distribution is Gaussian, or when it is not...

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have never studied Gaussian distribution, is there a more elementary example?

Comment: Let's say you are comparing blood pressure in 50 patients receiving drug A and 50 receiving drug B (having only follow-up blood pressure). Then, depending on the distribution of blood pressure, you cannot interpret a p value stemming from t test as you would with a Mann-Whitney, especially if the distribution is asymmetric/skewed (where the latter test would probably be more robust - and possibly more powerful).

Comment: @GiuseppeBiondi-Zoccai I see your point, but suppose both test statistics are actually sufficient statistics and we just happen to be able to exactly derive the distribution of the two test statistics, then are we certain that they always make the same decision at the same significance level?